# Unable to format miniSD card

Tags: partitioning, gparted, format

I have a 2GB mini-SD card that I am trying to format. The drive is currently formatted for use with a PandaBoard.

It has 2 partitions - 1 x FAT32 - 1 x ext3

Usually, I unmount the partitions then run the script that re-partitions the card ready for me to use with the PandaBoard.

However, if using Disk Utility I tell it to format with 'Don't Partition' it seems to do it, but when ejected and reinserted is back to the way it was.

The same thing happens with fdisk and gParted...

What can I do?

Windows won't touch it either and my MacBookPro says the device is busy the whole time!

Very confusing as I am fairly new to the linux world!

Answer (score 1):

Your MiniSD seems Damaged in some way. Since its not only your pc, I suggest you try another SD card.